# how can i intercept and change my ip with something else

Tags: wireshark

I am using windows 7 desktop and wire-shark to track activities.

i am requesting video from rtsp://r3---sn-5hnedn7s.googlevideo.com.  in wire-shark i see my source address witch is my ipv4 address 192.xxx.xx.xx.

Wireshark:

[image: click here to see the image and wireshark]

How i can change the source address to anything else?

Comment: It depends how your IP address is configured (either provided by DHCP or statically set). Anyway, this is off-topic here.

Comment: my house has a router and i connect using wifi , its static ip

Comment: am just doing heavy load of searching not finding anything , something like intercept data change modify and send , am vb6 and vb.net programmer but first i need to know how to intercept this , what protocol is it.  i know the rtsp is using port 544

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are you trying to do? A man-in-the-middle attack? Why would you change the ip?